# What to do if in react-native DeviceMotion is not available?

Tags: android, react-native, devicemotion

In my react-native app I use `DeviceMotion` from `expo-sensors`, when running `await DeviceMotion.isAvailableAsync()` line it returns `false`.
In any documentation that I read, it's not said what to do in this case. Is it a limitation of the device itself? Or is there a way to enable it? I couldn't find anything in settings. How do I enable it if it is possible?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? i am facing the same issue.